# Reading only Doubles don't work

Tags: java, double

I have a problem reading double values from txt file. My program only converts ints to doubles, but i want to ignore them.

Example file:

```
1 2 3 4.5
5 6 7 8.1
9 10 11 12.7
```

Here is my code:

```
File file = new File("file.txt");

    try{
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        scanner.useLocale(Locale.US);
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()){
            if (scanner.hasNext() && scanner.hasNextDouble()){
                double value = scanner.nextDouble();
                System.out.println(value);
            }
        }
    }catch(FileNotFoundException e){}
```

My output is:

```
1.0
2.0
3.0
4.5
5.0
6.0
7.0
8.1
9.0
10.0
11.0
12.7
```

Comment: What's your question? What do you *want* the output to be?

Comment: If you scan and assign it to a double variable, it would be a double. Whats your problem ?

Comment: My problem is that i want to iterate over txt files and get only double values.

Comment: @Erik `1` and `10` are also valid double values.

Comment: Change code of the form `catch (Exception e) { ..` to `catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); // very informative! ..`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, Integers can be represented as Doubles, so `Scanner` will pick them up when you ask it to find Doubles. You'll have to either check for Integer values manually after you scan them in, or else use `Scanner.nextInt` to skip over integer inputs and only use `nextDouble` when you (temporarily) run out of Integers. So your conditional inside your loop would look something like this:

```
if (scanner.hasNext()) {
    if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
        scanner.nextInt(); // Ignore this value since it's an Integer
    } else if (scanner.hasNextDouble()){
        double value = scanner.nextDouble();
        System.out.println(value);
    }
}
```

Although to be perfectly honest, I'm a little confused why you're using `hasNextLine()` as the condition for your `while` loop, since this requires you to check separately for `hasNext()`, as you're doing now. Why not just do this?

```
while (scanner.hasNext()) { // Loop over all tokens in the Scanner.
    if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
        scanner.nextInt(); // Ignore this value since it's an Integer
    } else if (scanner.hasNextDouble()){
        double value = scanner.nextDouble();
        System.out.println(value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well then check if it has an integer as the next token, with [`.hasNextInt()`.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
if (scanner.hasNext()) {
        double value = scanner.nextDouble(); // Ignore this value since it's an Integer
        if (!value.toString().endsWith(".0"))
             System.out.println(value);
    }
}
```

It will break if you're not using standard numerals, but I'm not aware of any places that aren't. The reason for your error is that java converts int to double implicitly.